# How to get total JVM heap size, used memory using Java

Tags: java, heap-memory, java-memory-model

pro-grammatically how to get total Heap size, used heap memory ?

Comment: can you tell the reason why you need this info ?

Comment: @Arkantos for some Private reasons...

Answer (score 4):

You can use Runtime class methods

`maxMemory() , freeMemory() and totalMemory()`

and if you want to use any  tools then there are so many tools like jProfiler.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `MemoryMXBean` to get info about your heap

```
MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
System.out.println(mbean.getHeapMemoryUsage());
```

which outputs

```
init = 134217728(131072K) used = 2044912(1996K)
committed = 128974848(125952K) max = 1897922560(1853440K)
```